# MYSQLi UPDATE doesn't work unless I modify the first column

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using `mysqli` with prepared statements and I tried to make a form to update the data from a row. But it only works when I modify the first column. I searched a lot and found nothing. The server doesn't display any errors, just does nothing if I don't modify the first field from the form.

I'm trying to make an online database of terms in guarani language. Now I'm writting a form to update a term information.

I have two pages: the first page is a form to search and select a term.
The id from selected term is passed to the second page.

**The second page:**
1° Verifies if the submit button from an update-form is sent in order to update the information of the term in the database, else
2° gets the id from selected term, which was passed from the first page, else
3° shows a message "you must select a term to modify it".

I reorganize better my code. I'm sorry for my english. I tried to translate some things to make the revision easier.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ypy_style.css" />
<title>Introducir termino nuevo</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content-wrapper">

<?php include'zayvu_header.php';?>

<div id="principal">
<b><h2>Ayvu Ñemoambue</h2></b><br>
<?php 
//*****************VERIFY IF  ENVIAR IS PRESSED***********************************

    //Comprueba si se presiono el boton ñemboguapy
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){ // SE HIZO ENVIAR

        include("../joapyra/aka_joaju_tuicha.php");
    include("../joapyra/aka_secure_data.php");

        // conectarse a la base de datos
    $dblink= new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // verificar la conexion
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            echo "Ndaikatúi ñambojoaju base de datos rehe:". mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
    }

    //Inicializa las variables a partir de los datos del formulario
    $id_seguro= secure_data($dblink, $_POST['idact']);
    $ayvu_seguro=  secure_data($dblink, $_POST['ayvu']);
    $heiseva_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['heiseva']);
    $nhenohehague_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['nhenohehague']);
    $ijepurupy_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['ijepurupy']);
    $ysajareko_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['ysajareko']);
    $nheejoapykuaa_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['joapykuaa']);
    $heijoja_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['heijoja']);
    $heiavy_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['heiavy']);
    $haimbohasa_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['haimbohasa']);
    $atygua_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['atygua']);
    $mboguapyhara_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['mboguapyhara']);
    $arange_seguro=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['arange']);


        //Comprueba si estan vacios los campos importantes
    if(empty($ayvu_seguro)|| empty($heiseva_seguro) || empty($mboguapyhara_seguro)){
        $error_message = "This fields: ayvu, he'iséva or mboguapyhára must be filled.";
        }else{ //ELSE SI NO ESTAN VACIOS

            if (!$stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT ayvu FROM ayvuryru WHERE ayvu=?")){

                $error_message = "error in the statement.";

            }else{
                // unir parametros con marcadores
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $ayvu_seguro);

                // ejecutar pedido
                $stmt->execute();

                // Almacenamos el resultado
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Obtenemos el número de filas que ha devuelto la consulta
                $NumeroRegistros = $stmt->num_rows;

                if ( $NumeroRegistros > 0 ) {

                        $error_message = "This ayvu is already registered.";

                }else{ //ELSE INSERTAR DATOS

                    if (!$stmt = $dblink->prepare("UPDATE ayvuryru SET ayvu= ?, heiseva= ?, nhenohehague= ?, ijepurupy= ?, ysajareko= ?, heijoja= ?, heiavy= ?, nheejoapykuaa= ?, haimbohasa= ?, atygua= ?, mboguapyhara= ?, arange= ? WHERE id= ?")) {

                                $error_message = "Error in the statement.";
                    }else{
                                // unir parametros con marcadores
                    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $ayvu_seguro, $heiseva_seguro, $nhenohehague_seguro, $ijepurupy_seguro, $ysajareko_seguro, $heijoja_seguro, $heiavy_seguro, $nheejoapykuaa_seguro, $haimbohasa_seguro, $atygua_seguro, $mboguapyhara_seguro, $arange_seguro, $id_seguro);

                    // ejecutar pedido
                    $stmt->execute();

                                echo "The information of ayvu is updated";
            }
                }

            }   

      } //ELSE SI NO ESTAN VACIOS

     //Cierra la conexion
     mysqli_close($dblink); 

} else{
?>
<?php
//**********************GET DATA FROM FIRST PAGE**********************
?>

<?php
//Inicia la variable de error
$error_message = "";
$satisfactorio = "";

//Comprueba si se presiono el boton nhemboguapy
 if(!isset($_POST['selected_ayvu'])){

     echo "You must select an ayvu to modify it.";

     echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</body>";
     echo "</html>";
 }else{
 ?>
<?php
//*****************IF A WORD IS SELECTED, PREPARES FORM TO UPDATE***********************
    $actualizable = $_POST['selected_ayvu'];
    echo $actualizable;
        include("../joapyra/aka_joaju_tuicha.php");
        include("../joapyra/aka_secure_data.php");

        // conectarse a la base de datos
    $dblink= new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // verificar la conexion
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            echo "Ndaikatúi ñambojoaju base de datos rehe.". mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
    }
        $id=secure_data($dblink, $_POST['selected_ayvu']);

        //prepara el statement
        if (!$stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT ayvu, heiseva, nhenohehague, ijepurupy, ysajareko, nheejoapykuaa, heijoja, heiavy, haimbohasa, mboguapyhara, arange, atygua FROM ayvuryru WHERE id=?")){

             $error_message = "Error in the statement.";

        }else{
            // Pasar los parametros a los marcadores
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

            // Ejecutar el pedido
            $stmt->execute();


            // Almacenar los datos para poder usar num_rows
            $stmt->store_result();

            if( $stmt->num_rows <= 0) {
                echo "no se encontro nada.";
            }
            //unir resultado variables del resultado
            $stmt->bind_result($ayvu, $heiseva, $nhenohehague, $ijepurupy, $ysajareko, $nheejoapykuaa, $heijoja, $heiavy, $haimbohasa, $mboguapyhara, $arange, $atygua);
            //entregar resultado
            $stmt->fetch();
            ?>
    <p>Emyatyr&#245; ayvu rehegua ha upéi ejopy "ñemboguapy"pe.</p>
<div id="formularionhemboguapy">

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
<?php    

?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="idact">
Ayvu<br/><input type="text" name="ayvu" value="<?php echo $ayvu;?>"><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
Atygua<br/><input type="radio" name="atygua" value="tero" checked>tero
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="teroja">teroja
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="terarangue">terarängue
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="nheeteva">ñe'ëtéva
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="nheeteja">ñe'ëteja
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="nheeriregua">ñe'ëriregua<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="joajuha">joajuha
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="nheendyi">ñe'ëndýi
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="moteiha">moteïha
        <input type="radio" name="atygua" value="nheepehetai">ñe'ëpehëtai<br/>
He'iséva<br/><textarea name="heiseva" id="heiseva" cols="55" rows="2"><?php echo $heiseva; ?></textarea><br/>
Ñenohehague<br/><textarea name="nhenohehague" id="nhenohehague" cols="40" rows="3"><?php echo $nhenohehague; ?></textarea><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
Ijepurupy<br/><textarea name="ijepurupy" id="ijepurupy" cols="55" rows="2"><?php echo $ijepurupy;?></textarea><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
Ysajareko<br/><textarea name="ysajareko" id="ysajareko" cols="55" rows="2"><?php echo $ysajareko;?></textarea><br/>
Ñe'ejoapykuaa<br/><textarea name="joapykuaa" id="joapykuaa" cols="55" rows="2"><?php echo $nheejoapykuaa;?></textarea><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
He'isejoja<br/><input type="text" name="heijoja"  value="<?php echo $heijoja;?>"><br/>
He'ise'avy<br/><input type="text" name="heiavy" value="<?php echo $heiavy;?>"><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
Haimbohasa<br/><input type="text" name="haimbohasa" value="<?php echo $haimbohasa;?>"><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<fieldset class="ayvurehegua">
Mboguapyhára<br/><input type="text" name="mboguapyhara" value="<?php echo $mboguapyhara;?>"><br/>
Arange<br/><input type="text" name="arange" value="<?php echo $arange;?>"><br/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="conjuntocampos">
<br/><input type="submit" class="boton" value="nhemboguapy" name="enviar">  <input type="reset" class="boton" value="oï ypyva'ekue"><br/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<?php

}            


?>
<?php } // CIERRA ALTERNATIVA A NO SE ELIGIO AYVU ?>
<?php } // CIERRA ALTERNATIVA A VERIFICACION DE SI SE HIZO ENVIAR ?>
<?php } // CIERRA ALTERNATIVA A SI NO ESTA LOGUEADO ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What database columns do you have? When you say you have to "modify the first column" for it to work, what column is it you have to update and what type is it (varchar, int, etc)?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer. I have these columns: id, ayvu, heiseva, nhenohehague, ijepurupy, ysajareko, heijoja, heiavy, nheejoapykuaa
haimbohasa, atygua, mboguapyhara, arange. And in the form, if I don't modify "ayvu" it doesn't update any other column. If I modify anything from "ayvu" it saves the modifications in other fields. I don't understand why is that.

Comment: I reorganize my code to make it easier to read. I read it many times and I still can't find where is the problem. All columns are text, "id " is int and "arange" is date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problems. First, there were some variables, which names didn't match.
Second, after I checked that the fields $ayvu, $heiseva and $mboguapyhara were not empty. I have a piece of code that checks if $ayvu already exists in the database. If $ayvu exists it doen't update anything. There was the biggest problem. This part:

```
if (!$stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT ayvu FROM ayvuryru WHERE ayvu=?")){

                $error_message = "error in the statement.";

            }else{
                // unir parametros con marcadores
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $ayvu_seguro);

                // ejecutar pedido
                $stmt->execute();

                // Almacenamos el resultado
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Obtenemos el número de filas que ha devuelto la consulta
                $NumeroRegistros = $stmt->num_rows;

                if ( $NumeroRegistros > 0 ) {

                        $error_message = "This ayvu is already registered.";
```

Three days of headache to find my own mistake!